/tmp/fz3temp-2/index.php does not exist or is not a plain file
I recently upgraded to ubuntu 24.04 LTS and after upgrading I am not able to same name file from filezila in edit mode on my netbean editor.
Here are the error screenshots



What are you attempting to do when  you get that error message?

I am opening a file in edit mode from filezila
